# Why can't I fire the longbow "Shift"?

Tags: lands-of-lore-god

Whenever I try to shoot this bow, there's a spark in my view that lights up the area, but nothing is fired.
Other bows fire arrows even if I'm not near enemies. This is the GoG.com version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Longbow "Shift" detects which element (fire/lightning/...) is the enemy susceptible to, and shoots the relevant type of projectile. If there are no susceptible enemies nearby, the longbow does not function.